# Angular Material Tree Add Child Button to Every Node

Tags: angular, tree, angular-material, treeview

https://stackblitz.com/angular/qkjdynkykodo?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftree-checklist-example.html

in this sample, "add child button" only show at parent node, I want to show add button at all child and parent node so I can create new levels for all nodes not only parent nodes.

[sample output image at link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywkXS.jpg)

[What i want and transform this sample to my requirement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S98Hu.jpg)

```
My Html
<mat-tree [dataSource]="dataSource" [treeControl]="treeControl">
  <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node" matTreeNodeToggle matTreeNodePadding>
    <button mat-icon-button disabled></button>
    <mat-checkbox class="checklist-leaf-node"
                  [checked]="checklistSelection.isSelected(node)"
                  (change)="todoLeafItemSelectionToggle(node)">{{node.item}}</mat-checkbox>
                     <button mat-icon-button (click)="addNewItem(node)"><mat-icon>add</mat-icon></button>
  </mat-tree-node>

  <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node; when: hasNoContent" matTreeNodePadding>
    <button mat-icon-button disabled></button>
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>New item...</mat-label>
      <input matInput #itemValue placeholder="Ex. Lettuce">
    </mat-form-field>
    <button mat-button (click)="saveNode(node, itemValue.value)">Save</button>
  </mat-tree-node>

  <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node; when: hasChild" matTreeNodePadding>
    <button mat-icon-button matTreeNodeToggle
            [attr.aria-label]="'Toggle ' + node.item">
      <mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror">
        {{treeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right'}}
      </mat-icon>
    </button>
    <mat-checkbox [checked]="descendantsAllSelected(node)"
                  [indeterminate]="descendantsPartiallySelected(node)"
                  (change)="todoItemSelectionToggle(node)">{{node.item}}</mat-checkbox>
    <button mat-icon-button (click)="addNewItem(node)"><mat-icon>add</mat-icon></button>
  </mat-tree-node>
</mat-tree>


<!-- Copyright 2020 Google LLC. All Rights Reserved.
    Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that
    can be found in the LICENSE file at http://angular.io/license -->

My TS Code
import {SelectionModel} from '@angular/cdk/collections';
import {FlatTreeControl} from '@angular/cdk/tree';
import {Component, Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {MatTreeFlatDataSource, MatTreeFlattener} from '@angular/material/tree';
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs';

/**
 * Node for to-do item
 */
export class TodoItemNode {
  children: TodoItemNode[];
  item: string;
}

/** Flat to-do item node with expandable and level information */
export class TodoItemFlatNode {
  item: string;
  level: number;
  expandable: boolean;
}

/**
 * The Json object for to-do list data.
 */
const TREE_DATA = {
  Groceries: {
    'Almond Meal flour': null,
    'Organic eggs': null,
    'Protein Powder': null,
    Fruits: {
      Apple: null,
      Berries: ['Blueberry', 'Raspberry'],
      Orange: null
    }
  },
  Reminders: [
    'Cook dinner',
    'Read the Material Design spec',
    'Upgrade Application to Angular'
  ]
};

/**
 * Checklist database, it can build a tree structured Json object.
 * Each node in Json object represents a to-do item or a category.
 * If a node is a category, it has children items and new items can be added under the category.
 */
@Injectable()
export class ChecklistDatabase {
  dataChange = new BehaviorSubject<TodoItemNode[]>([]);

  get data(): TodoItemNode[] { return this.dataChange.value; }

  constructor() {
    this.initialize();
  }

  initialize() {
    // Build the tree nodes from Json object. The result is a list of `TodoItemNode` with nested
    //     file node as children.
    const data = this.buildFileTree(TREE_DATA, 0);

    // Notify the change.
    this.dataChange.next(data);
  }

  /**
   * Build the file structure tree. The `value` is the Json object, or a sub-tree of a Json object.
   * The return value is the list of `TodoItemNode`.
   */
  buildFileTree(obj: {[key: string]: any}, level: number): TodoItemNode[] {
    return Object.keys(obj).reduce<TodoItemNode[]>((accumulator, key) => {
      const value = obj[key];
      const node = new TodoItemNode();
      node.item = key;

      if (value != null) {
        if (typeof value === 'object') {
          node.children = this.buildFileTree(value, level + 1);
        } else {
          node.item = value;
        }
      }

      return accumulator.concat(node);
    }, []);
  }

  /** Add an item to to-do list */
  insertItem(parent: TodoItemNode, name: string) {
    if (parent.children) {
      parent.children.push({item: name} as TodoItemNode);
      this.dataChange.next(this.data);
    }
  }

  updateItem(node: TodoItemNode, name: string) {
    node.item = name;
    this.dataChange.next(this.data);
  }
}

/**
 * @title Tree with checkboxes
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'tree-checklist-example',
  templateUrl: 'tree-checklist-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['tree-checklist-example.css'],
  providers: [ChecklistDatabase]
})
export class TreeChecklistExample {
  /** Map from flat node to nested node. This helps us finding the nested node to be modified */
  flatNodeMap = new Map<TodoItemFlatNode, TodoItemNode>();

  /** Map from nested node to flattened node. This helps us to keep the same object for selection */
  nestedNodeMap = new Map<TodoItemNode, TodoItemFlatNode>();

  /** A selected parent node to be inserted */
  selectedParent: TodoItemFlatNode | null = null;

  /** The new item's name */
  newItemName = '';

  treeControl: FlatTreeControl<TodoItemFlatNode>;

  treeFlattener: MatTreeFlattener<TodoItemNode, TodoItemFlatNode>;

  dataSource: MatTreeFlatDataSource<TodoItemNode, TodoItemFlatNode>;

  /** The selection for checklist */
  checklistSelection = new SelectionModel<TodoItemFlatNode>(true /* multiple */);

  constructor(private _database: ChecklistDatabase) {
    this.treeFlattener = new MatTreeFlattener(this.transformer, this.getLevel,
      this.isExpandable, this.getChildren);
    this.treeControl = new FlatTreeControl<TodoItemFlatNode>(this.getLevel, this.isExpandable);
    this.dataSource = new MatTreeFlatDataSource(this.treeControl, this.treeFlattener);

    _database.dataChange.subscribe(data => {
      this.dataSource.data = data;
    });
  }

  getLevel = (node: TodoItemFlatNode) => node.level;

  isExpandable = (node: TodoItemFlatNode) => node.expandable;

  getChildren = (node: TodoItemNode): TodoItemNode[] => node.children;

  hasChild = (_: number, _nodeData: TodoItemFlatNode) => _nodeData.expandable;

  hasNoContent = (_: number, _nodeData: TodoItemFlatNode) => _nodeData.item === '';

  /**
   * Transformer to convert nested node to flat node. Record the nodes in maps for later use.
   */
  transformer = (node: TodoItemNode, level: number) => {
    const existingNode = this.nestedNodeMap.get(node);
    const flatNode = existingNode && existingNode.item === node.item
        ? existingNode
        : new TodoItemFlatNode();
    flatNode.item = node.item;
    flatNode.level = level;
    flatNode.expandable = !!node.children?.length;
    this.flatNodeMap.set(flatNode, node);
    this.nestedNodeMap.set(node, flatNode);
    return flatNode;
  }

  /** Whether all the descendants of the node are selected. */
  descendantsAllSelected(node: TodoItemFlatNode): boolean {
    const descendants = this.treeControl.getDescendants(node);
    const descAllSelected = descendants.length > 0 && descendants.every(child => {
      return this.checklistSelection.isSelected(child);
    });
    return descAllSelected;
  }

  /** Whether part of the descendants are selected */
  descendantsPartiallySelected(node: TodoItemFlatNode): boolean {
    const descendants = this.treeControl.getDescendants(node);
    const result = descendants.some(child => this.checklistSelection.isSelected(child));
    return result && !this.descendantsAllSelected(node);
  }

  /** Toggle the to-do item selection. Select/deselect all the descendants node */
  todoItemSelectionToggle(node: TodoItemFlatNode): void {
    this.checklistSelection.toggle(node);
    const descendants = this.treeControl.getDescendants(node);
    this.checklistSelection.isSelected(node)
      ? this.checklistSelection.select(...descendants)
      : this.checklistSelection.deselect(...descendants);

    // Force update for the parent
    descendants.forEach(child => this.checklistSelection.isSelected(child));
    this.checkAllParentsSelection(node);
  }

  /** Toggle a leaf to-do item selection. Check all the parents to see if they changed */
  todoLeafItemSelectionToggle(node: TodoItemFlatNode): void {
    this.checklistSelection.toggle(node);
    this.checkAllParentsSelection(node);
  }

  /* Checks all the parents when a leaf node is selected/unselected */
  checkAllParentsSelection(node: TodoItemFlatNode): void {
    let parent: TodoItemFlatNode | null = this.getParentNode(node);
    while (parent) {
      this.checkRootNodeSelection(parent);
      parent = this.getParentNode(parent);
    }
  }

  /** Check root node checked state and change it accordingly */
  checkRootNodeSelection(node: TodoItemFlatNode): void {
    const nodeSelected = this.checklistSelection.isSelected(node);
    const descendants = this.treeControl.getDescendants(node);
    const descAllSelected = descendants.length > 0 && descendants.every(child => {
      return this.checklistSelection.isSelected(child);
    });
    if (nodeSelected && !descAllSelected) {
      this.checklistSelection.deselect(node);
    } else if (!nodeSelected && descAllSelected) {
      this.checklistSelection.select(node);
    }
  }

  /* Get the parent node of a node */
  getParentNode(node: TodoItemFlatNode): TodoItemFlatNode | null {
    const currentLevel = this.getLevel(node);

    if (currentLevel < 1) {
      return null;
    }

    const startIndex = this.treeControl.dataNodes.indexOf(node) - 1;

    for (let i = startIndex; i >= 0; i--) {
      const currentNode = this.treeControl.dataNodes[i];

      if (this.getLevel(currentNode) < currentLevel) {
        return currentNode;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  /** Select the category so we can insert the new item. */
  addNewItem(node: TodoItemFlatNode) {
    const parentNode = this.flatNodeMap.get(node);
    this._database.insertItem(parentNode!, '');
    this.treeControl.expand(node);
  }

  /** Save the node to database */
  saveNode(node: TodoItemFlatNode, itemValue: string) {
    const nestedNode = this.flatNodeMap.get(node);
    this._database.updateItem(nestedNode!, itemValue);
  }
}


/**  Copyright 2020 Google LLC. All Rights Reserved.
    Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that
    can be found in the LICENSE file at http://angular.io/license */
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I did not find any straight forward solution. But we can hack it. Angular consider two node type in a tree, one is expandable and another is not. If a node has no children then it is no expandable thus the add child button is not shown. We can trick angular of thinking that every node is expandable. So we need to make some modification to the code.

First, add `hasChild:boolean` property inside `TodoItemFlatNode` class:

```
export class TodoItemFlatNode {
    item: string;
    level: number;
    expandable: boolean;
    hasChild:boolean; // new property
}
```

Then inside `ChecklistDatabase` class edit the `insertItem()` function as follows (or it will throw an error):

```
insertItem(parent: TodoItemNode, name: string) {
    if (!parent.children) parent.children=[];
    parent.children.push({ item: name } as TodoItemNode);
    this.dataChange.next(this.data);
}
```

Edit the `transfer()` function inside `TreeChecklistExample` component class like this:

```
transformer = (node: TodoItemNode, level: number) => {
    ...
    flatNode.expandable = true;                   // edit this to true to make it always expandable
    flatNode.hasChild = !!node.children?.length;  // add this line. this property will help 
                                                     //us to hide the expand button in a node
    ...
};
```

We are done with .ts, Now we will make some modification to the html code.

1. Delete the first `<mat-tree-node>` as we don't need it anymore.
2. In Third `<mat-tree-node>` remove `; when: hasChild` from `*matTreeNodeDef`
3. Add `*ngIf="node.hasChild"` to the toggle button to make it disappear when node has no children
4. Add `<div *ngIf="!node.hasChild" class="pad"></div>` below the button to fill up the space when expand button is hidden.

```
<mat-tree [dataSource]="dataSource" [treeControl]="treeControl">
  /////// delete the first <mat-tree-node>

  <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node; when: hasNoContent" matTreeNodePadding>
    <button mat-icon-button disabled></button>
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>New item...</mat-label>
      <input matInput #itemValue placeholder="Ex. Lettuce">
    </mat-form-field>
    <button mat-button (click)="saveNode(node, itemValue.value)">Save</button>
  </mat-tree-node>

  <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node" matTreeNodePadding>
                   ///////////// remove "; when: hasChild" from *matTreeNodeDef

    <button mat-icon-button matTreeNodeToggle
            [attr.aria-label]="'Toggle ' + node.item"
            *ngIf="node.hasChild">   ////////// add this to make expand button 
                                             // appear when has child

      <mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror">
        {{treeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right'}}
      </mat-icon>
    </button>

    //////////// add this line to make space for removed button
    <div *ngIf="!node.hasChild" class="pad"></div>

    <mat-checkbox [checked]="descendantsAllSelected(node)"
                  [indeterminate]="descendantsPartiallySelected(node)"
                  (change)="todoItemSelectionToggle(node)">{{node.item}}</mat-checkbox>
    <button mat-icon-button (click)="addNewItem(node)"><mat-icon>add</mat-icon></button>
  </mat-tree-node>
</mat-tree>
```

Finally add this style in .scss:

```
.pad {
    width: 40px;
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hdejsg?file=src/app/tree-checklist-example.html